# How to get all messages from a thread from Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've already searched extensively online for this and can't seem to find a solution. Using the Graph API explorer, when I input /thread-id/comments, it gives me around 15-ish messages by default. I've tried doing stuff like /thread-id/comments?=limit and comments?until=date but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody know how to get rid of this invisible limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can only try to increase the limit, but there is a max value afaik and the proper way to get more items is to implement paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging